# How do I do a dictionary lookup in a list of permutations of that dictionary?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

If I have a dictionary of airport locations like this one:

```
airports = {"JFK": (40.639751, -73.778925, 0.9488), "AAL":(57.092789, 9.849164, 0.134), "CDG": (49.012779, 2.55, 1),
        "SYD": (-33.946111, 151.177222, 0.7253), "LHR": (51.4775, -0.461389, 1.4029)}
```

And I get all the permutations of that dict in a list by:

```
from itertools import permutations

print(list(permutations(airports, 5)))
```

which gives me:

```
[('AAL', 'SYD', 'JFK', 'LHR', 'CDG'), ('AAL', 'SYD', 'JFK', 'CDG', 'LHR'), ('AAL', 'SYD', 'LHR', 'JFK', 'CDG')...#all permutations
```

How do I do a dictionary lookup of gps coordinates for each airport in that list of permutations?

On a side note, what I am trying to do is create these 120 permutations so I have every possible way someone could travel between these airports and then calculate the great circle distance travelled between each airport (and then multiplied that distance in km by  the third value in the dictionary from the airport one is travelling from to convert it to euros). The cost of each of the 120 4-leg journies is calculated find the cheapest way to visit those five cities.

Any help with the dictionary lookup would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to lookup values in a dictionary *generally*? How to iterate over a tuple? What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: To lookup the dictionary above before performing the permutation function, I would do the following: 'code' long1 = airports["JFK"][0]
lat1 = airports["JFK"][1]
toEuro = airports["JFK"][2]
print(long1, lat1, toEuro)'

Comment: So... **what are you stuck on** (note that that could be `long1, lat1, toEuro = airports['JFK']`)?

Comment: Nothing now. Thanks. @Matt Davidson answered it below. I had a nested for loop but I was leaving out the get() and ending up just getting the airport codes back e.g. "JFK" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the GPS co-ordinates you can take advantage of Python's iterable looping structure:

```
for perm in permutations:
    for airport in perm:
         print(airports.get(airport))
```

You then ask about calculations on this data structure, looking for the least expensive path. This algorithm is known as the Travelling Salesman problem, and is a classic Computer Science conundrum. I recommend you read more!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: Thanks Matt! I was leaving out the get(). I will have a good read of that wiki page now!